# You "(j)yu + ci or zi" my question

Tags: cantonese

I don't understand these two characters Luk Ho Ming speaks at [50:26](https://youtu.be/EALkUVWUerU?t=5026). Just to clarify, he's speaking in background. He's not  lad seated next to Ceci Mak.

> 好好. 您我_ _嘅问题。

> My translation — Good. You _ _ my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "好好，你**預知咗**我條问题呀。" (Good, good, you'**ve anticipated** my question)

> [預知](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/12134/) /jyu6 zi1/:  anticipate, foresee

> 咗 = 了 (indicates the verb is completed)